# Embedded C: How to apply the MAP macro to two arguments at a time instead of one?

Tags: c, dictionary, macros, embedded, variadic

I want to modify or use in a tricky way this https://github.com/swansontec/map-macro macro for using map in my C sources as follows:

```
MAP(f,1,2,3)
   f(1)
   f(2)
   f(3)
```

into

```
MAP2(f,a,1,2,3)
   f(a,1)
   f(a,2)
   f(a,3)
```

How should I?

Comment: Please don't use that macro, meta programming with macros is _horrible_ programming practice. Use function pointers in a loop instead. Seriously.

Comment: Hi Lundin, thanks for writing. I want to "generate" some code with X-Macros that have a variable argument list. I am not using them just to "loop"  :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In the end, it was clear that using C preprocessor is bad and should be avoided as much as possible in the real world.

I decided to use auto-generation of code using python and **COG**, the **CO**de **G**enerator: https://nedbatchelder.com/code/cog/index.html#h_the_cog_module

By wrapping python code inside a comment, I was able to selfgenerate all I wanted, no matter how complex it was.

Much easier, flexible and 2017 friendly than relying on preprocessor.

Answer (score 0):

Just call `MAP()` with a macro for the function name, where the macro expansion inserts your argument:

```
#define F(x) f(a,x)
```

Then in your function:

```
MAP(F, 1, 2, 3);
```

Result is:

```
f(a, 1); f(a, 2); f(a, 3);
```

(Not endorsing the approach, just providing an answer to the question.)

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use this solution because a should be another macro argument and is not known in advance.